# Null Value not Getting Replaced by jQuery/Conditional

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, null

I am running into the issue of some of the data objects I am pulling through do not have any data attached to it, so it is posting "- null" in place of the empty data (which is the expected behavior).

I have implemented a conditional if statement `if (results == null){ $('#report-summary').text("There were no notes");}`, and the null value is still getting returned?

Here is my **UPDATED** JS & it still returns null;

```js
function loadData(url) {
    url = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('WeeklyReport')/items?$select=DeliverablesSubmitted,MajorTasks,PersonnelActions,SupportRequest,ResourceRequest,Team,Training,Upcoming,WeekOf,TravelODC";
    return fetch(url, { headers: { accept: "application/json; odata=verbose" } }) // make request
      .then((r) => {
        if (!r.ok) throw new Error("Failed: " + url);  // Check for errors
        return r.json();  // parse JSON
      })
      .then((data) => data.d.results);
  }
  loadData()
    .then((results) => {
        const data = results;
        var listContent = [];
      
      for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
           listContent += '<li data-weekOf="'+data[i].WeekOf+'">';
           listContent += '<h2 id="teamname">' + data[i].Team  +'</h2>';
           listContent += '<h4 id="tasks"> Tasks </h4>';
           listContent += '<ul>' + "- " + data[i].MajorTasks + '</ul>';
           listContent += '<h4 id="deliverables"> Deliverables </h4>';
           listContent += '<ul>' + "- " + data[i].Deliverables + '</ul>';
           listContent += '<h4 id="actions"> Actions </h4>';
           listContent += '<ul>' + "- " + data[i].Actions + '</ul>';
           listContent += '<h4 id="events"> Upcoming Events </h4>';
           listContent += '<ul>' + "- " + data[i].Upcoming + '</ul>';
           listContent += '<h4 id="training"> Training </h4>';
           listContent += '<ul>' + "- " + data[i].Training + '</ul>';
           listContent += '<h4 id="resource"> Resource Request </h4>';
           listContent += '<ul>' + "- " + data[i].Resource + '</ul>';
           listContent += '<h4 id="support"> Support Request </h4>';
           listContent += '<ul>' + "- " + data[i].Support + '</ul>';
           listContent += '<h4 id="travel"> Travel </h4>';
           listContent += '<ul>' + "- " + data[i].Travel + '</ul>';
           listContent += '</li>';
         }
         if (results !== null){
      $('#report-summary').html(listContent);
  }else{
      $('#report-summary').text("There were no notes");
  }
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        alert("Error: " + err);
        console.error(err);
      });
```

Comment: `if(results == null) $('#report-summary').text("There were no notes")` ?

Comment: Also `.then((results) => {  return results; });` is useless, it doesn't do anything

Comment: @JeremyThille I removed the second .then, I realized that. if(results == null) would I call that in the load data function? or before appending the html to listContent

Comment: @JeremyThille see my most recent edit, it still returns null

Comment: This isn't the problem but you are initiating listContent as an array `var listContent = [];` but you are appending content to it like a string. So I would change that to `var listContent = "";`

Comment: @imvain2 thank you I didn't pay attention to that, do you have any clue related to the question I asked

Comment: @bigchungus, I see that your `if` statement is actually overridden on the next line after it. You are basically saying If null show `There were no notes`, then replace that will the null values. Wrap your loop with `if (results !== null){` then have a `else{$('#report-summary').text("There were no notes");}`

Comment: @imvain2 see my most recent edit, I did that, but it still only returns - null.

Comment: When you `console.log(data)` it has the correct information?

Comment: @imvain2 it does. Here is an example of one of the values it returns in the string of data.d.results "Training":null,

Comment: Your markup is stressing me. `li > ul > #text` is ... not right. And what `nodeName` has `#report-summary`? Since you add all these `<li>`s to it , it should be an `<ul>` or `<ol>` but you also do this: `$('#report-summary').text("There were no notes");` and `#text` does not belong in either of them. And all the `id`s in that markup will be used multiple times, for every entry in `data`; they should be unique throughout the entire document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was somewhat on the right track, in order to achieve my expected result, I had to nest the conditional within the original for loop like so:

```js
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
         listContent += '<li data-weekOf="'+data[i].WeekOf+'">';
         listContent += '<h2>' + data[i].Team  +'</h2>';
         listContent += '<h4> Tasks </h4>';
         if(data[i].Tasks !== null){
            listContent += '<ul>' + "- " + data[i].Tasks + '</ul>';
         }else{
              listContent += '<ul>' + "- There were no notes attached to this section." + '</ul>';
         }
         listContent += '<h4> Deliverables </h4>';
                 if(data[i].Deliverables !== null){
         listContent += '<ul>' + "- " + data[i].Deliverables + '</ul>';
         }else{
         listContent += '<ul>' + "- There were no notes attached to this section." + '</ul>';
         }
         listContent += '<h4> Personnel Actions </h4>';
                 if(data[i].Actions !== null){
         listContent += '<ul>' + "- " + data[i].Actions + '</ul>';
         }else{
         listContent += '<ul>' + "- There were no notes attached to this section." + '</ul>';
         }
         listContent += '<h4> Finance (Billable) </h4>';
                 if(data[i].Billable !== null){
         listContent += '<ul>' + "- " + data[i].Billable + '</ul>';
         }else{
         listContent += '<ul>' + "- There were no notes attached to this section." + '</ul>';
         }
         listContent += '<h4> Finance (Non-Billable) </h4>';
         if(data[i].NonBillable !== null){
                 listContent += '<ul>' + "- " + data[i].NonBillable + '</ul>';
         }else{
         listContent += '<ul>' + "- There were no notes attached to this section." + '</ul>';
         }
         listContent += '<h4> Upcoming Events </h4>';
         if(data[i].UpcomingEvents !== null){
         listContent += '<ul>' + "- " + data[i].UpcomingEvents + '</ul>';
         }else{
         listContent += '<ul>' + "- There were no notes attached to this section." + '</ul>';
         }
         listContent += '<h4> Training </h4>';
         if(data[i].Training !== null){
         listContent += '<ul>' + "- " + data[i].Training + '</ul>';
         }else{
         listContent += '<ul>' + "- There were no notes attached to this section." + '</ul>';
         }
         listContent += '<h4> Resource Request </h4>';
         if(data[i].Resource !== null){
         listContent += '<ul>' + "- " + data[i].Resource + '</ul>';
         }else{
         listContent += '<ul>' + "- There were no notes attached to this section." + '</ul>';
         }
         listContent += '<h4> Support Request </h4>';
         if(data[i].Support !== null){
         listContent += '<ul>' + "- " + data[i].Support + '</ul>';         
         }else{
         listContent += '<ul>' + "- There were no notes attached to this section." + '</ul>';
         }
         listContent += '</li>';
 }
   $('#report-summary').html(listContent);
```